# Rails ActiveRecord Update head record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I got a resource *invoice* and a resource *invoiceline*.

When I create, update or delete a invoiceline the *sum* column of the parent, the invoice, should update.

How is this achieved in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with callbacks, something like

```
class InvoiceLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :calculate_invoice_sum
  after_save :calculate_invoice_sum

  belongs_to :invoice

  def calculate_invoice_sum
    if invoice
      invoice.calculate_invoice_sum
    end
  end
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_lines

  def calculate_invoice_sum
    # assuming InvoiceLine has an amount attribute
    total = invoice_lines.sum(&:amount)
    update_attribute(:sum, total)
  end
end
```

you might want `before_` callbacks instead of `after`, but I think after makes more sense in this case

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum

Answer (score 1):

There is [`counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) option you can pass in to `belongs_to` association.  For your models, you'd define the `belongs_to` association as follows:

```
class InvoiceLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice, dependent: :destroy, counter_cache: :sum_column
end
```

Note that you should have the column name `sum_column` (for, example above) in your `invoices` table.

Comment: my guess is he wants to total the sum of each invoice_line amount, i think counter_cache will just update the count of invoice_line records?

Comment: The same question occured to me. How does it know which invoiceline column to sum up? If it just counts the sub-records that is fine and useful too but I would like to have the sum of all ammounts as @house9 said